# The callback function object in Django URLconf is not called

Tags: django, django-urls

I am learing Django on [Django at a glance | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/overview/)

When introducing URLconf It reads:

> To design URLs for an app, you create a Python module called a URLconf. A table of contents for your app, it contains a simple mapping between URL patterns and Python callback functions.

Nevertheless, a callback function is not called.

```
mysite/news/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
]
print('callback funtion:',views.year_archive)
```

output:

```
callback function: <function views.year_archive at 0x1039611e0>
```

So it a funtion object which is not called.

I suppose it should be `views.year_archive()` to enable it to call.

If not called,how does it work? I assume there a decorator to process it in parent class.

I check the source codes of `url`[django.conf.urls | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/conf/urls/#url)

The key statement is:

```
 elif callable(view):
        return RegexURLPattern(regex, view, kwargs, name)
```

I dig on to explore `LocaleRegexProvider`, `RegexURLPattern` [django.urls.resolvers | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/urls/resolvers/).
No appopriate codes were found to call the callback function `views.year_archive`

What's the mechanism of its working?

Comment: Do You get any error ? Coz when `DEBUG=True` Django should say that requested Url didnt match any pattern, so we can at start define where to start analyse. And function must be passed as object `views.year_archive` without parenthesis, coz then You would pass result callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django automatically calls the callback view function whenever a request is made to the given url pattern.

To understand how it works, look at this example:

```
>>> def a():
        print("Called function a")

>>> def b():
        print("Called function b")

>>> def c(callback):
        # call the callback function like this
        callback()

>>> c(a)
Called function a
>>> c(b)
Called function b
```

Basically, this is how Django's `url` function works.