# 'if' v.s. `while` to a `functools.partial.func`

Tags: python, django, callback, functools

In Django documentation [django.conf.urls | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/conf/urls/#url)

There's such codes:

```
class RegexURLPattern(LocaleRegexProvider):
    ...
    def lookup_str(self)
        callback = self.callback
        # Python 3.5 collapses nested partials, so can change "while" to "if"
        # when it's the minimum supported version.
        while isinstance(callback, functools.partial):
            callback = callback.func
        ...
```

The code is to callback the argument of funtion 'view' and execute it.

Why `while` is better than `if` excluding 'Python 3.5'?
There is only one callback argument passed in from `django.conf.urls.url`,which seen in:

```
def url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None):
    elif callable(view):
        return RegexURLPattern(regex, view, kwargs, name)
```

It seems `if` is more readable than `while`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about number of arguments but about the depth of how many times a callback was wrapped in another callback.

For one iteration, `while` is the same as `if` so that doesn't really matter. However, if someone called `lookup_str` with callback which was itself a callback, `while` would still just keep on to work.

Answer (score 0):

An impressive tutorial of `functools`
[Cleaner Code Through Partial Function Application - Blogomatono](http://chriskiehl.com/article/Cleaner-coding-through-partially-applied-functions/)
[The callback function object in Django URLconf is not called - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248175/the-callback-function-object-in-django-urlconf-is-not-called)